# In cockroachdb, how can I kill all long-running transactions with locks on a certain table?

Tags: cockroachdb

I have a table that I can't execute any statements against. I think this is because I have zombie transactions open with locks on the entire table. How can I drop all those transactions or otherwise unblock a blocked table?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is usually to run a high priority transaction on the table. This will cancel all regular priority transactions it contends with. The non-zombies will get retried by the client, but the zombies will with any luck be dead for good.

```sql
BEGIN PRIORITY HIGH;
SELECT count(*) FROM foo; -- Do something cheaper here if the table is large
COMMIT;
```